# Upgrade user count to 250 or more in visual studio 2010 load test user pack

Tags: visual-studio-2010, load-testing

I have visual studio 2010 license version but I am able to only add 250 user load and not more than that.how to improve user count to 250 to 1000 in load testing in visual studio 2010?so please help me out.
Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Visual Studio has a different licence policy than the newer releases. The 2012 and 2013 versions allow an unlimited number of users, although the trial versions have small limit. You could ask Microsoft, or your software supplier, about getting a licence for more than 250 users with the 2010 version, or you could upgrade to the latest version.

Answer (score 0):

Just to add to AdrianHHH's response, Visual Studio 2010 also allows for the unlimited number of users, with a licensed version (provided you have an MSDN subscription.)  See
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee850544(v=vs.100).aspx.

The 250 virtual user limit is on running them locally.  If you are using controllers and agents, the number of virtual users can be increased beyond 250.

Assuming you have the ability to execute tests remotely with the use of the load test controllers and agents, the number of virtual users is controlled in the Controller settings, after clicking the manage virtual users license.

Controller and agent setup is documented here:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh546459.aspx

Based on AdrianHHH's answer, it sounds like later versions may not require an MSDN subscription for unlimited virtual user's, but I don't know for sure.

In Visual Studio 2010, virtual users are added in increments of 1,000 by increasing the license count.  Adding virtual users is documented here:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff426120.aspx

Answer (score 0):

if you already have a license and get this error, please check if your agent machine name in Scenario property "Agents to use" is wrong